# How to get text value for the image near a click point?

Tags: android, google-maps, image-processing, android-canvas, ocr

[image: (custom defined plans of construction) and plot multiple points]

I have same image and want to get the click on particular point and need to get the text from that particular point, Do anyone have idea about how to draw this points in android with pinch zoom. I though to use android OCR go get the cut image and get text value.

Comment: is it a dynamic image (taken for example from a camera)?

Comment: its autocad images with point an i want to get click on each point and get the text of that click .

Comment: so you need OCR for it to work

Comment: ohh Thanks, do you have any idea of that? or idea of how to use this image as pinch zoom.